# How to increment a zero padded int in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a set of records to loop. The numbers range from 0000001 to 0089543 that ill call UIDX.

if i try something like:

```
for ((i=0; i< 0089543; i++)); do
    ((UIDX++))
done
```

counter increments 1, 2, 3, 4 as opposed to the 0000001, 0000002... that i need.

what is the best way to pad those leading zero's?

Comment: In any language, numbers and the display of numbers are separate issues. `000001` is just a formatting choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `printf` command to format the numbers with leading zeroes, eg:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 99; ++i)); do printf -v num '%07d' $i; echo $num; done
```

From `man bash`:

> printf [-v var] format [arguments]
>   Write the formatted arguments to the standard output under the control of the format.  The  -v  option causes the output to be assigned to the variable var rather than being printed to the standard output.

Answer (score 8):

Bash 4 has a nice way to solve this:

```
for i in {0000000..0089543}; do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the seq command, very useful in your situation

```
seq -w 0089543
```

Remove the first and last number according to your need, for example, if you need to arrive to 0089542 then the command to use is

```
seq -w 0089542
```

Comment: +1, thanks. I've so far always used string concatenation to achieve the effect.